# Including library in AIR Native Extension causes the error, "The extension context does not have a method with the name..." for all methods

Tags: c++, c, actionscript-3, dll, air

I am working on an AIR Native Extension (ANE) for Windows desktop.  The point of this extension is to be able to call out to a third-party C library, which consists of two .h files defining the method signatures/typedefs, and a .lib file.

Before including the third party library in the project, I first confirmed that I set up everything correctly by building the ANE with a simple "sayHello" function in the dll that just creates and returns a string.

Having verified that I can call sayHello from my AIR application and get a response, I proceeded to add a function that initializes the third-party library. This is where things went sideways.  My dll compiles just fine, and I'm able to package the ANE without error, but when I try to call any ANE function from AIR, I get the following error:

"`The extension context does not have a method with the name`..."

In AIR, the call to `createExtensionContext()` succeeds and returns an ExtensionContext object, but I'm not able to call any native functions.  What's more, Visual Studio's debugger no longer loads symbols for my dll - the dll does not appear in the modules window and I cannot set breakpoints in the native code.

If I comment out the line where I call the third-party library's initialize function, then everything works fine again - I can call all my functions and hit breakpoints in Visual Studio.

So basically, it appears that If I compile this library into my dll, then AIR will fail to load it.  What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ProcessMonitor, I found that the the third-party library has a dependency on an external dll, which it was not finding.  At the time the ExtensionContext is created, the runtime apparently attempts to resolve the dependencies of the ANE.  Since it could not find this dll, the ANE's initializer function was failing.  AIR still creates an ExtensionContext object in this situation, but since it is never successfully initialized, it does not know the names and locations of its functions.